# Pub/Sub or Service Bus with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, publish-subscribe, servicebus

We have a rails application that generates a lot of background tasks that need to be executed when certain events occur in the system (client notifications, third party data synchronization, dirty cache updatest to the relational database, etc.).  I was wondering if there were any open source solutions out there that people were particularly happy with.  Low operations overhead would be nice, but we need reliability most of all.

We've looked briefly at ActiveMQ and Rabbitt, are any others worth a look?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I have the save need, looking for a service bus that I can use from rails, have you found any?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) which is backed by Redis. It was developed by Github and is used for all sorts of background tasks. I have used it in combinationw with Rails apps and it works quite well.